# Is this translation of the original text correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading a translated copy in modern English of The Tempest. And one of the sentence of the original text which was

> All things in common nature should produce without sweat or endeavour.

Was translated into:

> Nature would produce everything people needed, and all of it would be shared equally by all.

According to me, the original sentence just means that the nature should produce everything by itself without any human attempt. But there is no implication that it will be distributed equally. So, is the translation incorrect? English is my third language so I tend to take analytical approach while construing sentence-meaning. But I'm having unprecedented trouble in doing so with "The Tempest". Is there any tip?

Comment: So what do you think *all things in common* means? I think it certainly means it should be shared; *"equally"* might be unjustified. But if you look at the whole passage, it says that Nature would produce more than enough for everyone (*abundance*), so sharing it exactly equally seems unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, that is a disgusting translation. As used here, *common* has the sense of things pertaining to the people's welfare. It's an older meaning, basically, [commonweal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commonweal). *Municipal* shares roots and senses. "But nature should bring forth
Of its own kind all foison, all abundance, To feed my innocent people". This may be an ecological and economic manifesto, but it isn't a Marxist one. Nature's duty to man ends with the production part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Tempest is difficult enough even if English is your first language!

The translation has correctly changed *should* to *would* because nowadays *should* (in this context) would mean *ought to*, and Gonzalo does NOT mean *All things in common nature **ought to** produce...* He means *All things in common nature **would** produce...*

In other words, where Shakespeare might have said, "If I were king I **should** do such-and-such", we nowadays would say, "If I were king I **would** do such-and-such".

> But there is no implication that it will be distributed equally.

"All things in common" means "Everything would be shared". It's all in the powerful word **common**. In medieval England most of the land was common: shared by the *commoners* - the ordinary folk - who grazed their animals on it, collected firewood, caught fish from its streams and so on. Perhaps by Shakespeare's day some people looked back on that period (wrongly!) as a Golden Age, 'all foison, all abundance.'

"without sweat or endeavour" means "without (anyone) having to toil."

Comment: “If I were king, I should do such-and-such” is still perfectly normal. In some cases, _should_ still cannot be changed to _would_, even (“I should bloody well think so!”). But that sense of _should_ is now limited to conditional constructions and cannot be used if there is no condition, like here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the 'common'='distributed' connection, as I don't think the syntax supports that. Perhaps 'common nature' refers to the natural state that we all share, as the old sense of the 'commons' suggests. So perhaps a loose translation might be "Those things *we all need* shouldn't require herculean efforts." It's a tricky one.

"(But) nature should bring forth of its own kind all foison, all abundance, to feed my innocent people." Gonzalo makes it clear that the 'nature' he speaks of is not the people, but that which sustains them. So perhaps 'common' in the sense of 'all around us.' In context, Gonzalo requires no work of us at all, no magistrates, no treason, gun etc.